# Why an immutable reference can work in match when mutable reference is required by function in Rust?

Tags: rust

Hi I'm currently reading *The Rust Programming Language* book. In error handling chapter I found this code works well:

```rs
fn read_username_from_file() -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    let f = File::open("hello.txt");

    let mut f = match f {
        Ok(file) => file,
        Err(e) => return Err(e),
    };

    let mut s = String::new();

    match f.read_to_string(&mut s) {
        Ok(_) => Ok(s),
        Err(e) => Err(e),
    }
}
```

However, after rewritting using `?` operator, the code only works in this way:

```rs
fn read_username_from_file() -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    let mut f = File::open("hello.txt")?;

    let mut s = String::new();

    f.read_to_string(&mut s)?;

    Ok(s)
}
```

Please note that `f` now become mutable! In the first version `f` is immutable. The definition of `read_to_string` is `fn read_to_string(&mut self, buf: &mut String) -> Result<usize>`, which requires a mutable `self` reference. But why the first version works without an compile time error here? `f` (`self`) is not mutable here!

Comment: In the first version `f` is not immutable. Yes, the first `let f` is immutable, but the subsequent shadowed `let mut f` is mutable. :)

Comment: @vallentin Thanks a lot! You're right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version, the *first* `f` is immutable, but then you shadow it and bind `f` mutably:

```rust
fn read_username_from_file() -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    let f = File::open("hello.txt"); // this is immutable

    let mut f = match f { ... } // this is mutable
}
```

The [`read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_string) function takes a mutable reference to `self`, so in *both* examples, `f` is required to be mutable.